# Editing WooCommerce checkout page billing address fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I want to edit the billing address of WooCommerce checkout page. I want to edit the billing State of my checkout page. I tried editing it by first doing this in my child theme.

Then I have tried editing class-wc-checkout.php file:

```
// Billing address
$billing_address = array();
    if ( $this->checkout_fields['billing'] ) {
        foreach ( array_keys( $this->checkout_fields['billing'] ) as $field ) {
            $field_name = str_replace( 'billing_', '', $field );
            $billing_address[ $field_name ] = $this->get_posted_address_data( $field_name );
        }
    }
```

Without success. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Important advice:** Never touch WooCommerce plugin core files avoiding:

> - Important errors
> - Losing the changes you have done when plugin is updated

---

> **To customize WooCommerce** you can:

> - [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) *(copying templates to your active theme)*.
> - [Use actions and filters hooks](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) *(in function.php file of your active theme).*

---

To **edit / create / remove / reorder checkout fields** we can use this 2 filter hooks:

- **`'woocommerce_checkout_fields'`**

or in specific cases you need to use the

- **`'woocommerce_default_address_fields'`** *(applied to all billing & shipping default fields below)*

Here the list of billing and shipping default fields:

```css
country
first_name
last_name
company
address_1
address_2
city
state
postcode
```

For example, to make the **`'billing_state'`** field required:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

    // we are changing here billing_state field to required
    $address_fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = true;

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Each field contains an array of properties that you can edit:

```css
type – type of field (text, textarea, password, select)
label – label for the input field
placeholder – placeholder for the input
class – class for the input
required – true or false, whether or not the field is require
clear – true or false, applies a clear fix to the field/label
label_class – class for the label element
options – for select boxes, array of options (key => value pairs)
```

Checkout fields are divided into 4 groups:

- shipping fields
- billing fields
- account fields
- order fields (notes, comments)

---

References:

- [**Official:** Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2)
- [Reordering checkout fields in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields/38265060#38265060)
- [Reorder billing fields in WooCommerce Checkout template](http://mayur210.blogspot.fr/2015/11/how-to-reorder-billing-fields-in.html)
- [How to reorder billing fields in WooCommerce Checkout template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/how-to-reorder-billing-fields-in-woocommerce-checkout-template)

Comment: i Cannot edit billing state,Postal code and other fields in biling details section of checkout page in woocommerce @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Just to correct a typo in the example:

$fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = true;
should be:
$address_fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = true;

Otherwise the filter won't work.