# WooCommerce - Checkout conditional fields for different persons custom status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I need to modify the checkout process for an woocommere website. The process is determinated by the status of the person that could be one of this: 
- **`'legal entity'`** 
- **`'individual'`**

I need to have a selector **`'User status'`** *(or radio buttons)*, just after the 'billing_first_name' and 'billing_last_name'.

> The selector should work this way:
>
> 1. If **`'legal entity'`** is selected, it should display 3 fields:
>
>    - 'phone_number'
>    - 'email'
>    - 'serial_id'
> 2. If **`'individual'`** is selected, it should display 3 other fields:
>
>    - 'custom_field1'
>    - 'custom_field2'
>    - 'custom_field3'

I tried WooCommerce Checkout Manager and another plugin but the problem is that I can't make matching conditions.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: after the user will complete the last name. the structure is like this:

- first name
- last name
- status of the person
a) legal entity:
b) individual

if is it a), will show up : phone number, email, and serial ID

if it will be b) will show up: other 3 fields

and after this the classic fields.

Comment: As your question is too broad, I would help only if you split your questions: Part 1 (NOW) Making the new checkout custom billing fields and reordering billing fields (to match what you want)… Then (AFTER) on an other question: Making the conditional part (which needs jQuery (javascript) and maybe ajax). So please edit your question To have only Part 1

Comment: I need to modify the checkout process for an woocommere website. The process is determinated by the status of the person that could be one of this: 
- 'legal entity' 
- 'individual'

I need to have a selector 'User status' (or radio buttons), just after the 'billing_first_name' and 'billing_last_name'.


The selector should work this way:

If 'legal entity' is selected, it should display 3 fields:
'phone_number'
'email'
'serial_id'

Comment: I have understood your question (no need to explain), but your question is too broad for one question… Read again my First comment please… If you approve, I will post here only the Part 1. After this, with the code of my answer, you will ask another question on a new thread for Part 2… DO YOU AGREE … If you agree, Just comment here, With "I agree to split my question". Once done, I will answer Part 1 HERE…

Comment: oo, I understood now, i thought that you want to post another question.. of course, I agree to split my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For WooCommerce 3+ *(update)*:**

> Since **WooCommerce 3.0 checkout fields** have changed a little bit so is not possible to reorder fields as before.
>
> There is a new **'priority'** argument **that handle fields order**, for checkout fields and my account fields as well.

Below I am just updating the part related to ordering fields:

```
## 3. Ordering the billing fields

// Set the order of the fields
$billing_fields_new_order = array(
    'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_status',
    'billing_email',      'billing_phone',     'billing_serial_id',
    'billing_custom1',    'billing_custom2',   'billing_custom3',
    'billing_company',    'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
    'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
);

$count = 0;
$priority = 10;

// Updating the 'priority' argument
foreach($billing_fields_new_order as $field_name){
    $count++;
    $fields['billing'][$field_name]['priority'] = $count * $priority;
}

// END: returning the customized checkout fields
return $fields;
```

**Reference:** [Reordering checkout fields in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce-3/38265060#38265060)

---

**Original answer:**

You need to use **`woocommerce_checkout_fields`** hook. Then first create the new fields. After Customize some field classes. To finish reorder the field to match your desire.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

// 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

    // The "status" selector
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('User status', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Chose an option', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
        '' => 'Chose an option',
        '1' => 'Legal entity',
        '2' => 'Individual'
    );

    // The "Serial ID" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group1');
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial_id']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial_id']['label'] = __('Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial_id']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');

    // The "Custom 1" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom1']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom1']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom1']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom1']['label'] = __('Custom name 1', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom1']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your custom1', 'my_theme_slug');

    // The "Custom 2" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom2']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom2']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom2']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom2']['label'] = __('Custom name 2', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom2']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your custom2', 'my_theme_slug');

    // The "Custom 3" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom3']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom3']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom3']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom3']['label'] = __('Custom name 3', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_custom3']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your custom3', 'my_theme_slug');


// 2. Customizing 'billing_email' and 'billing_phone' fields ['class']

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first', 'status-group1');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-last', 'status-group1');


// 3. Ordering the billing fields

    $fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_status',
        'billing_email',      'billing_phone',     'billing_serial_id',
        'billing_custom1',    'billing_custom2',   'billing_custom3',
        'billing_company',    'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
    );
    foreach($fields_order as $field) $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    $fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;
    

// Returning Checkout customized billing fields

    return $fields;

}
```

Naturally this goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme

This code is tested and fully functional.

> *Now with this code, yo can ask a question to handle the "conditional" part of this question (as I have tell you in comments)…*

Official reference: [WooThemes - Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: ok, I did it what you told me, what should I do next? 


 
what I don't understand is that, the wocommerce has already phone number and email. I don't need to add another fields.. is that ok?

Comment: @BursucAndrei My code didn't create email and phone. I have just reorder existing phone and email. Now with the code of my answer, you can create your new question, saying that you have this code for creating/ordering the checkout fields and that you would like to have (the 2nd part of your question). When done, Post the link Here, please.