# Custom dropdown selector showing or hiding other Checkout custom fields

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I use this code to create custom checkout fields and reorder fields:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

// 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

    // The "status" selector
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('User status', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Chose an option', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
        '' => 'Chose an option',
        '1' => 'Legal entity',
        '2' => 'Individual'
    );

    // The "Serial ID" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group1');
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['label'] = __('Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');

    // Customizing 'billing_company' field ['required']
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;

    // The "Serial ID" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group1');
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial']['label'] = __('Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_serial']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your Serial ID', 'my_theme_slug');


// 2. Customizing 'billing_email' and 'billing_phone' fields ['class']

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first', 'status-group1');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-last', 'status-group1');


// 3. Ordering the billing fields

    $fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
        'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
        'billing_status',
        'billing_company',   'billing_number_id',  'billing_serial'
    );
    foreach($fields_order as $field) $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    $fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;


// Returning Checkout customized billing fields

    return $fields;

}
```

**The conditional mechanism:**

1. By default, the **`billing_status` dropdown selector will be on `Individual`** option value and will show **only `billing_serial`** custom field.
2. When the `billing_status` dropdown selector will switched to `"Company"`** option value , 2 more fields will appear:

   - **`billing_company`** existing field (before **`billing_serial`**)
   - **`billing_number_id`** custom fields (at the end)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

---

Reference: [WooCommerce - Checkout conditional fields for different persons custom status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973024/woocommerce-checkout-conditional-fields-for-different-persons-custom-status/39009245#39009245)

Comment: It's simple, the user will complete only name, and surname, after this he will choose the status of his person if it is a legal entity or an individual.

If he will choose from the dropdown selector menu the individual status, the field that needs to show up will be phone, address, email, and serial id.

If he is a legal entity, I need the following fields:
- phone
- email
- address
- serial id number for the company
- and 3 others fields

Comment: ok, the reason that I want this structure is that if I want to bring on the invoice this data in depending the type of the person. Make sense now?

Comment: Bringing the data to thankyou and invoice is going to be future other questions, I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For WooCommerce 3+ *(update)*:**

> Since **WooCommerce 3.0 checkout fields** have changed a little bit so is not possible to reorder fields as before.
>
> There is a new **'priority'** argument **that handle fields order**, for checkout fields and my account fields as well.

Below I am just updating the part related to ordering fields:

```
## 3. Ordering the billing fields

// Set the order of the fields
$billing_fields_new_order = array(
    'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
    'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
    'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
    'billing_status',
    'billing_company',   'billing_number_id',  'billing_ser_id'
);

$count = 0;
$priority = 10;

// Updating the 'priority' argument
foreach($billing_fields_new_order as $field_name){
    $count++;
    $fields['billing'][$field_name]['priority'] = $count * $priority;
}

// END: returning the customized checkout fields
return $fields;
```

**Reference:** [Reordering checkout fields in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce-3/38265060#38265060)

---

**Original answer:**

Here is a solution with a jQuery/JS script to make working the conditional mechanism just as you expect… The php code is completed with some necessaries functions…

**PHP code** (goes in function.php):

```php
// Registering external jQuery/JS file
function cfields_scripts() {
    
    /* IMPORTANT NOTE: For a child theme replace get_template_directory_uri() by get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
                       The external cfields.js file goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme.*/
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'checkout_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/cfields.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cfields_scripts' );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

// 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

    // The "status" selector
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('User status', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Chose an option', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
        '1' => __( 'Individual', '' ),
        '2' => __( 'Company', '' )
    );

    // Customizing 'billing_company' field ['required']
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');

    // The "Number ID" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['label'] = __('Number ID', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_number_id']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your Number ID', 'my_theme_slug');

    // The "Serial identification" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['label'] = __('Serial identification', 'my_theme_slug');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your Serial identification', 'my_theme_slug');


// 3. Ordering the billing fields

    $fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
        'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
        'billing_status',
        'billing_company',   'billing_number_id',  'billing_ser_id'
    );
    foreach($fields_order as $field) $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    $fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;


// Returning Checkout customized billing fields

    return $fields;

}


// Process the checkout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_number_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Number ID.', 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_ser_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Serial id.' , 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );
}

// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_number_id'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_number_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_number_id'] ) );
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_ser_id'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_ser_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_ser_id'] ) );
}


// Display field value on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My number ID').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_number_id', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My serial identification').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_ser_id', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

**Javascript `cfields.js` code** (external file):

```js
// This file named "cfields.js" goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    });
    $('#billing_ser_id_field').hide(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    });
    $("#billing_number_id_field").addClass("validate-required");

    $("#billing_status").change(function(){
        if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "2"){
            $('#billing_company_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
            });
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
            });
        } else if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1"){
            $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            });
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            });
        }

    });

});
```

**All this code has been tested and works**

Comment: Hello Loic, I have a little problem, I want to add 3 more fields for the legal entity: bank name, bank account & registration number.. i can't do it, can you help me, thanks in advance.. @loictheaztec