# Displaying custom checkout fields based on a selector choice

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Based on this working answer: 
[Custom dropdown selector showing or hiding other Checkout custom fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129295/checkout-custom-dropdown-selector-conditional-value-show-hide-other-custom-fiel/39181355#39181355)

In WooCommerce checkout page I use the code below to create some additional custom fields and reorder all the checkout fields. I use a jQuery script to show/hide some fields based on a selector choice.

Here is my new code:

```
// Registering external jQuery/JS file
function cfields_scripts() {

/* IMPORTANT NOTE: For a child theme replace get_template_directory_uri() by get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
                   The external cfields.js file goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme.*/

wp_enqueue_script( 'checkout_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/cfields.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cfields_scripts' );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

// 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

// The "status" selector
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('Statut Juridic', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Alege statutul', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
    '1' => __( 'Persoana Fizica', '' ),
    '2' => __( 'Persoana Juridica', '' )
);

// Customizing 'billing_company' field ['required']
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');

// The "Nr. registrul comertului" text field
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['type'] = 'text';
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['label'] = __('Nr. Reg. Comert', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['placeholder'] = __('Introdu numarul', 'my_theme_slug');

// The "Banca" text field
$fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['type'] = 'text';
$fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
$fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['label'] = __('Banca', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga Banca', 'my_theme_slug');

// The "IBAN" text field
$fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['type'] = 'text';
$fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
$fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['label'] = __('IBAN', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga IBAN-ul', 'my_theme_slug');

// The "CIF" text field
$fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['type'] = 'text';
$fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
$fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['label'] = __('Cod Fiscal', 'my_theme_slug');
$fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga CIF-ul', 'my_theme_slug');


// 3. Ordering the billing fields

$fields_order = array(
    'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
    'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
    'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
    'billing_status',
    'billing_company',  'billing_ser_id',       'billing_bt_id',
    'billing_ib_id', 'billing_cf_id'
    );
foreach($fields_order as $field) $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

$fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;


// Returning Checkout customized billing fields

return $fields;

}


// Process the checkout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process',     'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function custom_checkout_field_process() {
// Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ( ! $_POST['billing_ser_id'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Serial id.' , 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );
if ( ! $_POST['billing_bt_id'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Serial id.' , 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );
if ( ! $_POST['billing_ib_id'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Serial id.' , 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );
if ( ! $_POST['billing_cf_id'] )
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter your Serial id.' , 'my_theme_slug' ), 'error' );   
}

// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_ser_id'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_ser_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_ser_id'] ) );
if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_bt_id'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_bt_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_bt_id'] ) );
if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_ib_id'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_ib_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_ib_id'] ) );
if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_cf_id'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_cf_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_cf_id'] ) ); 
}


// Display field value on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My serial identification').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_ser_id', true ) . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My serial identification').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_bt_id', true ) . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My serial identification').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_ib_id', true ) . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>'.__('My serial identification').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_cf_id', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

**Javascript `cfields.js` code** *(**incomplete** external file)*:

```js
// This file named "cfields.js" goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    });
    $('#billing_ser_id_field').hide(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
    });
    $("#billing_number_id_field").addClass("validate-required");

    $("#billing_status").change(function(){
        if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "2"){
            $('#billing_company_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
            });
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
            });
        } else if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1"){
            $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            });
            $('#billing_ser_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            });
        }

    });

});
```

As I have some additional fields and what I need now is when the **`billing_status`** selector is on:

1. **Persoana Fizica** option value *(Individual)*: showing only **`billing_serial`** custom field.
2. **Persoana Juridica** option value *(Company)*, 4 more fields will appear:

   - **`billing_company`** existing field *(at first, before **`billing_serial`**)*
   - **`billing_registration_id`** custom field *(this field is always shown, in both cases)*
   - **`billing_bank_id`** custom field
   - **`billing_bankno_id`** custom field
   - **`billing_cif_id`** custom field

Also I would like to display this data on Thankyou Oder receive page and on email notifications.

I haven't find the way to get it working. How can I make it work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE [HERE FOR REORDERING CHECKOUT FIELDS IN WC 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce-3/38265060#38265060)

As you have add others customs fields and make some changes, you will find below the necessary code to make it work properly. *This is becoming a real development and shouldn't be asked in here. I try to always finish what I have began, so I answer it.*

> **The most difficult thing** here is to avoid WooCommerce alert notice on hidden required fields when selector is on **`Individual`**. For this you are obliged *(with the help of jQuery)* to imput a "no" value in that hidden fields.
>
> So when the order will be submitted, you will get all the custom fields values in the order meta data (for **`Individual`** your hidden fields will have a **`"no"`** value. **It's the only possible way.**
>
> But as we can process the displayed data and even update it afterwards, this is not a problem, as you will see…

**Here is the PHP code (which goes in function.php):**

```
 // Registering external jQuery/JS file
function cfields_scripts() {

    // IMPORTANT NOTE:
    // For a child theme replace get_template_directory_uri() by get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
    // The external cfields.js file goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'checkout_script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/cfields.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cfields_scripts' );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ba_custom_checkout_billing_fields' );
function ba_custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    // 1. Creating the additional custom billing fields

    // The "status" selector
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['type'] = 'select';
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['class'] = array('form-row-wide, status-select');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['label'] = __('Statut Juridic', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['placeholder'] = __('Alege statutul', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_status']['options'] = array(
        '1' => __( 'Persoana Fizica', 'theme_domain' ),
        '2' => __( 'Persoana Juridica', 'theme_domain' )
    );

    // The "Nr. registrul comertului" text field (this field is common)
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['required'] = true; // <== HERE has to be "true" as it always be shown and need validation
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['label'] = __('Nr. Reg. Comert', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ser_id']['placeholder'] = __('Introdu numarul', 'theme_domain');

    // The "Banca" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['label'] = __('Banca', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_bt_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga Banca', 'theme_domain');

    // The "IBAN" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['label'] = __('IBAN', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_ib_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga IBAN-ul', 'theme_domain');

    // The "CIF" text field
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['type'] = 'text';
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['class'] = array('form-row-wide', 'status-group2');
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['label'] = __('Cod Fiscal', 'theme_domain');
    $fields['billing']['billing_cf_id']['placeholder'] = __('Adauga CIF-ul', 'theme_domain');


    // 2. Ordering the billing fields

    $fields_order = array(
        'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_email',
        'billing_phone',      'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2',
        'billing_postcode',   'billing_city',      'billing_country',
        'billing_status',     'billing_company',   'billing_ser_id',
        'billing_bt_id',      'billing_ib_id',     'billing_cf_id'
    );

    foreach($fields_order as $field)
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields['billing'][$field];

    $fields['billing'] = $ordered_fields;


    // 4. Returning Checkout customized billing fields
    return $fields;

}


// Process the checkout (Checking if required fields are not empty)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_process');
function ba_custom_checkout_field_process() {

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_ser_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Nr. Reg. Comert</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_bt_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Banca</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_ib_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>IBAN</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );

    if ( ! $_POST['billing_cf_id'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Cod Fiscal</strong> is a required field.', 'theme_domain' ), 'error' );
}

// Adding/Updating meta data to the order with the custom-fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function ba_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    $billing_company = $_POST['billing_company'];
    $billing_ser_id  = $_POST['billing_ser_id'];
    $billing_bt_id   = $_POST['billing_bt_id'];
    $billing_ib_id   = $_POST['billing_ib_id'];
    $billing_cf_id   = $_POST['billing_cf_id'];

    // For Individual resetting billing company to "" (no value) instead of 'no'
    if ( !empty($billing_company) && 'no' == $billing_company )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_company', '' );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ser_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ser_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_bt_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_bt_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_ib_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_ib_id ) );

    // Adding/updating data only for companies
    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_cf_id', sanitize_text_field( $billing_cf_id ) );
}


// Display custom-field Title/values on the order edit page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'ba_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function ba_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){

    $output = '';
    $billing_ser_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ser_id', true );
    $billing_bt_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_bt_id',  true );
    $billing_ib_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ib_id',  true );
    $billing_cf_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cf_id',  true );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) ){
        $output .= '<p><strong>' . __( 'Nr. Reg. Comert', 'theme_domain' ) . ':</strong> ' . $billing_ser_id . '</p>';
    }

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id ){
        $output .= '<p><strong>' . __( 'Banca', 'theme_domain' ) . ':</strong> ' . $billing_bt_id . '</p>';
    }

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id ){
        $output .= '<p><strong>' . __( 'IBAN', 'theme_domain' ) . ':</strong> ' . $billing_ib_id . '</p>';
    }

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id ){
        $output .= '<p><strong>' . __( 'Cod Fiscal', 'theme_domain' ) . ':</strong> ' . $billing_cf_id . '</p>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

> To display the data on the customer order view, on **Thankyou** page, **My account order view** and on email notifications, add this 2 code snippets in your **`function.php`** file:

```
// Displaying data on order view in "customer details" zone
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details','ba_add_values_to_order_item_meta', 10, 1 );
function ba_add_values_to_order_item_meta( $order ) {

    $output = '';
    $billing_ser_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ser_id', true );
    $billing_bt_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_bt_id',  true );
    $billing_ib_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ib_id',  true );
    $billing_cf_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cf_id',  true );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Nr. Reg. Comert:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_ser_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Banca:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_bt_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "IBAN:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_ib_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Cod Fiscal:", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <td>' . $billing_cf_id . '</td>
        </tr>';

    echo $output;
}


// Displaying data on email notifications
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','ba_add_values_to_emails_notifications', 15, 4 );
function ba_add_values_to_emails_notifications( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    $output = '<ul>';
    $billing_ser_id = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ser_id', true );
    $billing_bt_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_bt_id',  true );
    $billing_ib_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_ib_id',  true );
    $billing_cf_id  = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_cf_id',  true );

    if ( !empty($billing_ser_id) )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Nr. Reg. Comert:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_ser_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_bt_id) && 'no' != $billing_bt_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Banca:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_bt_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_ib_id) && 'no' != $billing_ib_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "IBAN:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_ib_id . '</span></li>';

    if ( !empty($billing_cf_id) && 'no' != $billing_cf_id )
        $output .= '<li><strong>' . __( "Cod Fiscal:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_cf_id . '</span></li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';

    echo $output;
}
```

**Javascript `cfields.js` code** (external file):

```js
// This file named "cfields.js" goes in a subfolder "js" of your active child theme or theme

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Common Serial ID field
    if(! $("#billing_ser_id_field").hasClass("validate-required") ){
        $("#billing_ser_id_field").addClass("validate-required");
    }


    // The 4 Fields to hide at start (if not "Persoana Juridica")
    if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1"){
        $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_company').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
        });
        $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
            $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
            $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
        });
     }

    // Action with the selector (Showing/hiding and adding/removing classes)
    $("#billing_status").change(function(){
        // For "Persoana Juridica"
        if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "2")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').show(function(){
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_company').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').show(function(){
                $(this).children('label').append( ' <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>' );
                $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("");
            });
        }
        // For "Persoana Fizica"
        else if($("#billing_status option:selected").val() == "1")
        {
            $('#billing_company_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_company').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_bt_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_bt_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_ib_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_ib_id').val("no");
            });
            $('#billing_cf_id_field').hide(function(){
                $(this).children("abbr.required").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                $(this).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                $('#billing_cf_id').val("no");
            });
        }

    });

});
```

**All this code has been tested and works**

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I couldn't answer cuz' I was out of the town. I check this right now and it's working. Incredible job from you. Thanks for your help and I hope that this can help other people with the same problem. Have a nice day :)