# How to re-order Woocommerce checkout form fields?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the order of the Woocommerce checkout page fields, but it's not working for me. I have tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'bbloomer_move_checkout_fields_woo_3' );
function bbloomer_move_checkout_fields_woo_3( $fields ) {
  $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 3;
  return $fields;
}
```

It change the order for a while and then re-order the fields in the original format after a fraction of second. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Another related thread here (for WC 3+): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973024/woocommerce-checkout-conditional-fields-for-different-persons-custom-status/39009245#39009245

Answer (score 0):

In your child theme you can add this code

```
<?php 
     // order the keys for your custom ordering or delete the ones you don't need
    $mybillingfields=array(
     "billing_first_name",
    "billing_last_name",
    "billing_company",
    "billing_address_1",
    "billing_address_2",
    "billing_city",
    "billing_state",
    "billing_postcode",
    "billing_country",
    "billing_email",
    "billing_phone",
    );
    foreach ($mybillingfields as $key){
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $checkout->checkout_fields['billing']
    [$key], $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
    } 
?>
```

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/how-to-reorder-billing-fields-in-woocommerce-checkout-template)