# Reorder Woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am trying to reorder the billing fields on the checkout page but everything I tried so far is not working.

Here is the snippet I am currently trying:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields");

function order_fields($fields) {
  $order = array(
    "billing_first_name", 
    "billing_last_name", 
    "billing_country", 
    "billing_state", 
    "billing_address_1", 
    "billing_address_2", 
    "billing_email", 
    "billing_phone"
  );

  foreach($order as $field) {
    $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
  }

  $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
  return $fields;
}
```

Could something be overriding this snippet, because it used to work for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The method you are using no longer works (*since the WooCommerce 3.0.4 update - [link to github issue here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14618)*). It's not exactly a bug, but rather a change of spec.

To fix this, you simply need to adjust the priority of each of the fields to fit the order that you want.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "custom_override_checkout_fields", 1);
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['priority'] = 1;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['priority'] = 2;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['priority'] = 3;
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 4;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 7;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 8;
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 9;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 10;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 11;
    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_locale_fields' );
function custom_override_default_locale_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['state']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['address_2']['priority'] = 7;
    return $fields;
}
```

Please note that it's not the line in code that adjusts the placement in the order, but the priority assigned to the field. In this case, I changed the `['billing_state']` priority to `5` which is (*in this example*) after `['billing_country']` and before `['billing_address_1']`.

---

## EDIT:

As per the comments, this wasn't working for some reason (*it worked on my first test WooCommerce installation, but I managed to get it to fail after changing the store location*).

After some digging, I found that the default locale settings get applied on top of the override (*not sure how else to explain this, but bear with me*).

I managed to get an install running where the above code was not working, and managed to fix it by adding the following code as well:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_locale_fields' );
function custom_override_default_locale_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['state']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['address_2']['priority'] = 7;
    return $fields;
}
```

I have added the extra snippet to the first code block to validate the entire block.

Comment: $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['priority'] = 1;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['priority'] = 2;
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 3;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 4;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 7;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 8;
--This is displaying fields in the following order, first name, last, country, phone, mail, address1, address2, state

Comment: @YahyaHussein it's possible that there is another function doing the same thing (either in your theme file, or another plugin). My suggestion would be to adjust the priority of the filter to something like `add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "custom_override_checkout_fields", 999);` so that it runs __after__ any potential duplicate functions.

Comment: @YahyaHussein I've finally managed to replicate your problem, and have edited my answer to include an additional snippet to help. Have a look and let me know :)

Comment: it worked, thank you
it would be great if you can add more explanation about the reason and how your answer solves it

Answer (score 4):

As @Byeongin correctly mentions in his answer, apart from the backend ordering (that  @Frits answer covers) there is also **ordering that happens via JavaSrcipt** in the front-end when the user selects specific countries from the dropdown menu.

If you also want to stop this front-end reordering from happening, the best solution I've encountered so far would be to hook into the `woocommerce_get_country_locale` filter and remove the `priority` overrides that are added there.

Something like the following will do the trick (tested with WooCommerce `v3.5.4`):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', function( $locale ) {
    foreach ( $locale as $country_code => $locale_fields ) {
        foreach ( $locale_fields as $field_key => $field_options ) {
            if ( isset( $field_options['priority'] ) ) {
                unset( $field_options['priority'] );
            }

            $locale[ $country_code ][ $field_key ] = $field_options;
        }
    }

    return $locale;
} );
```

Comment: You should only do this if your shop ships to a single country only. When the user selects a different country, WooCommerce changes the order of address fields to match the user's expectations in terms of the locale, as addresses are different in each country. The JavaScript (`address-i18n.js` / `country.js`) sorts the fields by their country-specific priority.

Comment: @sun I agree with you — reordering the address fields could raise UX issues in the checkout when you are selling to multiple countries. The solution I posted above should be used only when you're aware of its UX-related fallbacks and you're sure about what you're doing. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I've been looking for this for ages, thanks! This is so annoying, why letting me overwrite the order, just to revert it on the frontend? So frustrating...

Answer (score 3):

To change woocommerce checkout fields you need to also change field order and required class base on display. you can add below code in functions.php and it work.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "woocommerce_reorder_checkout_fields", 9999);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_reorder_checkout_fields' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_reorder_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

        /* To reorder state field you need to add this array. */
        $order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_country", 
        "billing_state", 
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone"
        );

        foreach($order as $field) {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
        }

        $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;

        /* To change email and phone number you have to add only class no need to add priority. */

        $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'][0] = 'form-row-first';
        $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'][0] = 'form-row-last';

    return $fields;
    }
}
```

See attached image [image]
For more info check this [link](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/checkout-fields.html)

Comment: The issue they fixed using class and priority is styling! not order!

Comment: Yes, using priority you can change display order so i update my answer

Comment: Can you please send your live url?

Comment: http://bazarplay.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%B1/
  --please pick any product and proceed to checkout, I want billing_state to be before billing_address1

Comment: @YahyaHussein when you say nothing changed, have you tested it thoroughly? I tested this and can confirm it works...

Comment: @Reigel sorry for late response, yes I did test it, did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

The ordering(sorting) works on address-i18n.min.js not in php code.

[image]

In my case, I did something wrong on my js code. So, the ordering didn't work well( javascript stop there ).

Please check dev console and js error.

And this is php code which change only priority.

```
function rpf_edit_default_address_fields($fields) {

  /* ------ reordering ------ */
  $fields['country']['priority'] = 10;
  $fields['first_name']['priority'] = 20;
  $fields['last_name']['priority'] = 30;
  $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 40;
  $fields['address_2']['priority'] = 50;
  $fields['city']['priority'] = 60;
  $fields['state']['priority'] = 70;
  $fields['postcode']['priority'] = 80;

  return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'rpf_edit_default_address_fields', 100, 1 );
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

For WooCommerce > 4.0 you need to have a priority key, because it's using asort on the array just before printing it.

You can do this:

```
function order_fields( $fields ) {
    $i = 0;

    $order = array(
        "billing_email",
        "billing_customfield", <- this is your custom field
        "billing_company",
        "billing_cvr",
        "billing_ean",
        "billing_first_name",
        "billing_last_name",
        "billing_address_1",
        "billing_address_2",
        "billing_country",
        "billing_postcode",
        "billing_city",
        "billing_phone"
    );

    foreach ( $order as $field ) {
        $ordered_fields[ $field ] = $fields["billing"][ $field ];
        $ordered_fields[ $field ][ "priority" ] = ++$i;
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;

    return $fields;

}

add_filter( "woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields" );
```

Comment: It's a working code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change native woocommerce class
This method works with me.
In fact, woocommerce uses a class : form-row-first (css: float left)
end form-row-last: float right.
If you change the priority 2 to 1 but ccs class is form-row-last, the field will still be on the right.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields',1 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 3;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("adresse email");
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-left');
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['priority'] = 5;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("entreprise");
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['class'] = array('form-left');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 6;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("téléphone");
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-right');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['validate'] = array('phone');
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['priority'] = 3;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("entreprise");
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['class'] = array('form-left');

    return $fields;
}
```

Others fields like first_name, last_name, address_1, address-2, post_code, city, country, state must be placed in this filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields','custom_override_default_locale_fields');
function custom_override_default_locale_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['last_name']['priority'] = 1;
    $fields['last_name']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("nom");
    $fields['last_name']['class'] = array('form-left');
    $fields['first_name']['priority'] = 2;
    $fields['first_name']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("prénom");
    $fields['first_name']['class'] = array('form-right');
    $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 110;
    $fields['address_1']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("adresse 1");
    $fields['address_2']['priority'] = 120;
    $fields['address_2']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("adresse 2");
    $fields['postcode']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("code postal");
    $fields['postcode']['priority'] = 130;
    $fields['postcode']['class'] = array('form-left-small');
    $fields['city']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("ville");
    $fields['city']['priority'] = 140;
    $fields['city']['class'] = array('form-right-big');
    $fields['country']['priority'] = 4;
    $fields['country']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("pays");
    $fields['country']['required'] = true;
    $fields['country']['class'] = array('form-right','address-field','update_totals_on_change');
    $fields['state']['priority'] = 120;
    $fields['state']['label'] = mb_strtoupper("téléphone");
    $fields['state']['required'] = true;
    $fields['state']['class'] = array('form-right');
return $fields;
    return $fields;
}
```

AND CSS

```
.woocommerce form .form-right,
.woocommerce form .form-left,
.woocommerce form .form-left-small,
.woocommerce form .form-right-big {
    display: inline-block;
}
.woocommerce form .form-right,
.woocommerce form .form-left {
    width: 48%
}
.woocommerce form .form-right,
.woocommerce form .form-big-right {
    margin-left: 2% !important;
}
.woocommerce form .form-left,
.woocommerce form .form-left-small {
    margin-right: 2% !important;
}
.woocommerce form .form-big-right {
    width: 63%;
}
.woocommerce form .form-left-small {
    width: 33%;
}
.woocommerce form .woocommerce-input-wrapper strong {
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
```

RESULT :

[image]

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.