# How to add extra fields in new user registration in Chekout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce user can also create account in the checkout process. At this point, I am trying to add some extra fields (like Email, Password confirmation & checkbox for 'email me') if user select "Create an account?" checkbox (image attached for reference).

[image]

At present it only show "Create account password" fields. But I want to add 3 more fields after the "Create account password" like - password confirmation , Email confirmation & checkbox for email me.

How can i add this functionality? Which action hook should i have to use for storing the that data.

**I've tried the following - : -**

I used filter woocommerce_checkout_fields for adding the extra fields.It working but it only displaying the fields before the "Create an account" checkbox.
I am following this link for adding the extra fields - [add a custom checkout billing field under the last name in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668748/add-a-custom-checkout-billing-field-under-the-last-name-in-woocommerce)

**i am using the following code to add confirm E-mail Text Box**

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_checkou_form_fields');
    function custom_woocommerce_checkout_form_fields( $fields )
{
      $fields['billing']['billing_email_cnfrm'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Please Confirm Email Address', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => __('Please Confirm Email Address', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'class'       => array('form-row form-row-wide'),   // add class name
    );
}
```

Similarly I added the checkbox also - (Image attached)
[image]

Any Advice Please.

Comment: a bit conf by the question, you have already added these fields in the form. What do you want to do now ? If user clicks on registration, and if you want to add field for user registration then the form the the hooks are different !

Comment: Thanks @Alice for reply,I want to show these additional fields when user will check Create Account? checkbox. Setting of priorities is not working in this case