# Reorder a custom field on the my account page of the form (Edit Account)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

inspired by: [Reordering checkout fields in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261425/reordering-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce-3) And based on the answer of @LoicTheAztec I intend to reorder the fields on the page my account in the section (Edit Account) if I am not wrong, the file where the data comes from is: form-edit-account.php

in said form I have a custom field that shows the date of birth, this field is added by a plugin, but it is positioned at the end and I need it just below the last name. The field has a meta key: yith_birthday

Attached image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Those fields are hardcoded in the related template file: [form-edit-account.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.2/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php)… So you need to [override this template via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), no other way.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ok, in my theme I have that template. But what can I do to reorder that field (Birthday Date) that comes from the YITH Coupon Email System plugin? Should I add a field with the characteristics it currently has and place it where I want? it will work?

Comment: Ask directly in that YITH plugin support pages (I never use YITH plugins, sorry)… or may be try to move the hooks location (starting with `do_action(` ) in the template